# Scrollable view with text and ability to do something when specific phrase is tapped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to implement a view which will load text from sqlite database (every sentence in a text will have unique tag in database) and will allow to execute some code while sentence is clicked (on-click executed method should then scroll clicked sentence to the center of the screen and change it's color/background color/font size to emphasize it)

Is it possible without using webview and js/js-native bridge? Which approach should be taken to implement such a view? Any help and comments highly appreciated!

Comment: Is there anything wrong with doing this as a UITableView and having each sentence display in a custom cell.

Comment: but then click on a sentence will open new wiew with clicked sentence alone? Also i want my view with text in it not to be divided to cells, visually it should be normal scrollable view with text. Can it all be done with UITableView?

Comment: No, a click on a sentence will execute whatever code you put into tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:.  As for the visual part, it might take a bit of experimenting to see whether the sentences can be made to look right to you.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, you could also considering using NSAttributedString together the Core Text Framework and attribute each sentence and attach some extra info about. Next you lookup the attribute below the tap position of the view. Once you have that you can retrieve the extra info again and do whatever you want with the tap.

After the tap you could then alter the properties of that part of the text. E.g. different font colour etc.

This tutorial on the internet looked interesting:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/how-to-create-a-simple-magazine-app-with-core-text

Comment: Thanks Dusty, going to explore NSAttributedString & Core Text further. BTW, how you getting the attribute below the tap position of the view, by using gesture recognizer or there is other ways?